# C++ Sha1 issue with using char *

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
std::stringstream ss;

    std::string data;
    data = "hello worl";
    unsigned char digest[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    char *string1 = strdup(data.c_str());
    // do stuff with string1
    free(string1);

    SHA1((unsigned char*)&string1, strlen(string1), (unsigned char*)&digest);    

    char mdString[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH*2+1];

    for(int i = 0; i < SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
         sprintf(&mdString[i*2], "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[i]);

ss.str("");
ss << mdString;

 cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My output always the same..

```
./sha
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
```

Even i change the content of data to "hello panda" or "hello ki" also give me the same output.

Update:
I took away the free

```
user1@ubuntu:~/yes/coding$ g++ -o sha sha.cpp -lcrypto
user1@ubuntu:~/yes/coding$ ./sha
1bc8b06c5cd4e774195293ea00c959173d8d3789
user1@ubuntu:~/yes/coding$ ./sha
c8cf70c522fc564aedb5894a24613542702172ca
user1@ubuntu:~/yes/coding$ ./sha
83fbda098c3549ab1347d6cf708ac85092200423
user1@ubuntu:~/yes/coding$ ./sha
ea6ccffd78236e22da412ed90a852329f59f8fd5
user1@ubuntu:~/yes/coding$ ./sha
0413799befebcb23f5a5c970e48febc7f1aa27fb
user1@ubuntu:~/yes/coding$ ./sha
7bd8e7952c78e282b8c117f8c537c456b66207d9
```

The sha change everytime, even i did not change the content of data

Comment: Do you really call `free` on `string1` and then use it again?

Comment: The comment that I wrote with `// do stuff with string1` means that you need to do all the things you want to do with it __before__ the free. (I recognize this as copy-paste from an earlier question I answered)

Comment: Also, in this case, it is enough to do `string1 = data.c_str()` since you do not actually need to __copy__ to a new array. You just need a pointer to it for a C function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
char *string1 = strdup(data.c_str());
// do stuff with string1
free(string1);

SHA1((unsigned char*)&string1, strlen(string1), (unsigned char*)&digest);
```

There's your error.

- You created string1
- You used it
- You freed it
- You used it again

Don't free what you still need to use.

---

In addition to that:

```
SHA1((unsigned char*)&string1, strlen(string1), (unsigned char*)&digest);
```

What you're doing here is passing the address of `char* string1` converted to an `unsigned char*`. What you want to do is pass `string1` instead of `&string1`. The same applies to `digest`.

Comment: Could you show us your new code? You either still have undefined behavior or you're using a memory address as a value :p

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the address of string1 when passing it into the SHA1 function. However, string1 already is of type const char *. So just remove the &.

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code is a problem:

```
free(string1);

SHA1((unsigned char*)&string1, strlen(string1), (unsigned char*)&digest);
```

you call `free` on `string1` and then subsequently use `string1` again, this is undefined behavior. You need to call `free` only after you are completely done using `string1`. A second problem is here:

```
SHA1((unsigned char*)&string1, strlen(string1), (unsigned char*)&digest); 
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`string1` is already a `char *` taking the `&` address of `string1` gives you a `char **`. It is also not clear to me that using a `char *` when you need a `unsigned chat *` is ok since `char` can be either `signed` or `unsigned`.